# how to get AccessibilityManager instance in Xamarin

Tags: java, android, xamarin

In my app, I need to get AccessibilityManager instance, in order to call this

```
  AccessibilityManager am = (AccessibilityManager) getSystemService(ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE);
  boolean isAccessibilityEnabled = am.isEnabled();
  boolean isExploreByTouchEnabled = am.isTouchExplorationEnabled();
```

I am coding in Xamarin, so I need help getting the AccessibilityManager.

Comment: What is wrong with the code that you posted?

Comment: this is for java android, I am developing with Xamarin

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty much the same. Assuming you are calling from within an Activity:

```
var am = (AccessibilityManager)GetSystemService(Context.AccessibilityService);
bool isAccessibilityEnabled = am.IsEnabled;
bool isExploreByTouchEnabled = am.IsTouchExplorationEnabled;
```

Answer (score 0):

---

using Android.Views.Accessibility;
using Plugin.CurrentActivity;
...

protected override async void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

```
        CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Init(this, savedInstanceState);

        AccessibilityManager am = (AccessibilityManager)CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity.GetSystemService(Android.Content.Context.AccessibilityService);
        if (am.IsEnabled)
        { 
    ...
```

}
else
{
...
}
--------## Heading ##

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Plugin.CurrentActivity/2.1.0.4

Ok.